# How does PutEx work?

Tags: vba, vbscript

I have to translate some code from VB to C# and can't quite grasp how `PutEx` works, though I have read MSDN doc. In my case I have the following:

```
Set ObjUser = GetObject("LDAP://" + myPathVariable)
ObjUser.PutEx 1, "Company", 0
```

Could someone explain to me what this line does exactly?

What I understood is that the first parameter is the action (in this case `ADS_PROPERTY_CLEAR`), the second is the property name, and third is the property value. So this line will clear `ObjUser` of any data and then append these values?

If such is the case, why wouldn't we use `Put` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`IADs::Put()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746352.aspx) can set a value, but it cannot clear a value, meaning you can use the method to set a different value, but not to remove a value entirely (i.e. set an attribute to NULL). For the latter you must use [`IADs::PutEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746353.aspx).

More detailed explanation from the [Scripting Guy blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2005/03/23/how-can-i-set-an-active-directory-attribute-value-to-null/):

> Next we use these two lines of code to completely erase Ken Myer’s telephone number:
>
> ```
> objUser.PutEx ADS_PROPERTY_CLEAR, "telephoneNumber", 0
> objUser.SetInfo
> ```
>
> As you can see, we call the `PutEx` method and pass it three parameters: 1) the constant **`ADS_PROPERTY_CLEAR`** which, again, indicates the operation we want to perform; 2) **`telephoneNumber`**, the attribute we want to clear; and 3) **`0`**, a parameter required any time you clear an attribute. We then call the `SetInfo` method to write the changes back to Active Directory. If you re-run the script that retrieves a list of users who have phone numbers, Ken Myer will no longer appear in the list. That’s because he no longer has a phone number, not even one consisting of an empty string.